# Syntax error in ajax script

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a hard time arranging my ajax script very well and i thinking if i could help some help here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $follow_container = $('#follow_container');
      var follow = localStorage.getItem('follow');
      if (follow !== null) {
        $follow_container.html(follow).show()
      }
      $('.followclick').on('click', function(event) {
            if (follow == null) {
              $('#follow_container').load('http://mysite/news.asp', function() {
                  localStorage.setItem('follow', $follow_container.html());
                }
              });
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?  What isn't working?

Comment: what do you mean by *arranging my ajax* ? Please be more elaborate and post appropriate code

Comment: it tells me syntax error at the buttom of the script.

Comment: you have something unclosed.... just count the {} and the ()

Comment: @neiza: Well, the code you've posted is incomplete.  So if this is *all of your code* then, yes, you have a syntax error.  Because you haven't closed your `if` statement, your `click` handler function, the call to `on()`, your `ready` handler function, or the call to `ready()`.  You also appear to have an errant `}` near the end.  Post the exact code you're using and the exact error.  You need to format your code properly and close any code blocks you've opened.  The browser isn't going to just figure it out for you.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça, please can you fix it for me? i'm new in ajax

Comment: @David, this is the exact code. i'm finding it hard to complete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you open a block of code (using a `{`), you also have to close it.  Every time you open a function call (using a `(`), you also have to close it.  You code just sort of trails off without actually closing anything.

When you do this:

```
if (follow == null) {
```

Somewhere, later in the code, at the end of that `if` block, you need to do this:

```
}
```

When you do this:

```
on(
```

Somewhere, later, you need to do this:

```
)
```

So, putting all of that together... close your code blocks:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $follow_container = $('#follow_container');
    var follow = localStorage.getItem('follow');
    if (follow !== null) {
        $follow_container.html(follow).show()
    }
    $('.followclick').on('click', function(event) {
        if (follow == null) {
            $('#follow_container').load('http://mysite/news.asp', function() {
                localStorage.setItem('follow', $follow_container.html());
            });
        }
    });
});
```